# magento 2.4 sample-date download problem ,Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json', aborting

Tags: magento2.4, sample-data, auth.json

2.4 there is one code generator on my Magento account under token access key, how can i used them with MGID to deploy sample-data for user name and password ??

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, please follow the instructions at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html to get a public and private key, then paste the public key into the username and the private key in as the password.
If this does not work, I suggest having a read of the composer documentation to create an auth.json file and pasting the keys indirectly. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/http-basic-authentication.md for suggestions.